# How to move PDF files to Folders based on File size

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file, asp.net-core

I have 10 million files in a particular location.I want to group the files based on file size using Parallel ForEach in C#.let's say I have 5 files. each file 5 MB, I want to move 2 files to Folder1, the next 2 files to Folder 2, and the last one is to Folder3.so each folder containing PDF files cannot be more than 10 MB.

Sample

Folder1 -- File1,File2
Folder2 -- File3,File4
Folder3 -- File5.

Code Sample

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C://Data");;

Parallel.ForEach(files , file
{
   
var Total Size = file.Lenth;

});
```

Comment: What if one of the files is bigger than 10MB? What if the first two files are both 9MB followed by two files of 1MB? Would the first two files go into separate folders A and B and the last two files both go into another folder, C? Or would you want to try to fit the files as efficiently as possible into the folders? If the latter, then this is a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) which is an NP-Hard problem!

Comment: Why start with a `Parallel.ForEach`? when you are having trouble with something else. It would make sense to attempt the fundamental problem first before trying to delegate work to threads and complicating the problem

Comment: I guess the easiest way to do this would be to load all files sort by size, grab the largest first, then start filling up to 10mb with the smallest and repeat. Yeah sure there are likely better filling algorithms however this will likely be the fastest and give a reasonably good result

Comment: @MatthewWatson  first of all  File size not more than 10 MB for sure. and Next Yes you are right.what ever you are saying is the correct flow.A,B and C.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Don't you mean "grab the *smallest* first"? And then go through the items from smallest to largest, putting them in the first slot that they fit in. However, from the OP's comment, this isn't a bin packing problem, so it's just "first fit".

Comment: @MatthewWatson that would be another approach, however what i suggested would be o(n), But since isnt bin packing problem, that approach you suggest would be the best i guess

Comment: @Michael Randall yes I agree.

Comment: @MichaelRandall The sort would be O(N.Log(N)), of course, so it's not O(N).

Comment: @MatthewWatson no its only touching each file once,,, maybe it wasnt so clear... Anyway, all that aside, OP why not try something :)

Comment: @MichaelRandall I mean that a sort operation would inherently be O(N.Log(N)) - you said "sort by size" so I assume you mean to do a sort.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ahhh, sorting is free! *looks around nervously* :P Just kidding you are indeed right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating directories and moving files is an IO-bound operation, which means that trying to do it using `Parallel.ForEach()` is likely to make little difference (and may actually slow it down).

So your best approach will be just to use non-parallel code, for example:

```
public static void GroupFilesBySize(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder, long thresholdSize)
{
    long   currentSize = thresholdSize + 1; // Force first file to be placed into a new folder.
    int    currentFolder = 0;
    string currentDestination = ""; // Will be updated on first iteration.

    foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder).EnumerateFiles("*.pdf"))
    {
        if (currentSize + file.Length > thresholdSize)
        {
            currentSize = 0;
            ++currentFolder;
            currentDestination = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, currentFolder.ToString());
            Directory.CreateDirectory(currentDestination);
        }

        file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(currentDestination, file.Name));
        currentSize += file.Length;
    }
}
```

Note that you would probably want to do some exception handling here, to handle conditions such as disk full, file is locked etc.

Comment: Excellent. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group files into folder groups first (since you already have file names and lengths it does not make sence to parallel it), and then call Parallel for each group.

```
var folders = new List<List<string>>();

var currSize = 0L;
var currFolder = new List<string>();
foreach (var file in files) {
  if (currFolder.Count > 0 && currSize + file.Length > 10 * 1024 * 1024) {
    folders.Add(currFolder);
    currSize = 0;
    currFolder = new List<string>();
  }
 
  currFolder.Add(file.FullName);
  currSize += file.Length;
}
if (currFolder.Count > 0)
  folders.Add(currFolder);


int index = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(folders, folder => {

  var folderIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref index);
  foreach (var fileName in folder) {
    File.Move(fileName, dstFolder + "\" + folderIndex.ToString() + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `Parallel.ForEach()` for an IO-bound disk operation! Imagine the poor little disk heads flying backwards and forwards as they try to service all the IO requests! Even on an SSD the parallelisation will probably make it slower rather than faster.

Comment: @Michael Randall but Parallel.ForEach() loop is fast right.that's why I would like to use it. anyway let me check IO-bound disk operation issues also.

Comment: @Sudheer `Parallel.ForEach()` is only faster if the operations it's doing don't block. And if you're trying to move a load of files on disk at the same time, it's certainly going to block. (I guess you meant to address that reply to me rather than Michael)

Comment: @Matthew Watson Ok let me check.